# Azure Application Insight with NLog (Target not found)

Tags: c#, azure, nlog, azure-application-insights

I am trying to insert Logs via NLOG to azure application insight in console application. But it is not inserting to Application insight where as same code working when using ColouredConsole to show log sin console window.

Tried with programmatically as well, but still logs not going to Application insight.

Reference link :
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-logging
Under NLOG code followed.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess the reason why you face the error target not found is you set the wrong InstrumentationKey.

I suggest you could recheck the InstrumentationKey, which could found in the AI's overview like this:

[image]

Then you could use below code to test it.

Install the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget package

```
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

        ApplicationInsightsTarget target = new ApplicationInsightsTarget();

        target.InstrumentationKey = "key";
        LoggingRule rule = new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, target);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);

        LogManager.Configuration = config;

        Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example");

        logger.Trace("trace log message");

        Console.Read();
```

At last, you could find the record in the search feature.

[image]

---

Update:

Two application use the same AI:

[image]

Comment: I followed the above same steps , still not logging in application insight. I created Application Insight under website + mobile and i m using the console application for logging, still that logs will insert ?

Comment: If you set the right InstrumentationKey, it will still insert the logs into AI. Have you set the right InstrumentationKey?Do you face any error? In the output windows do you see the AI's logs?

Comment: Have you run the console application a part of time? Since the AI SDK translate the message need some time. I suggest you could add  Console.Read method at the end of the main method to wait the record has already translated to the azure AI.

Comment: I added & waited for at least 2-3 minutes.

Comment: This is very strange thing, I suggest you could create another AI and use my codes to test it again, make sure you use right InstrumentationKey. I have also create another application to test it it works well as my update answer.